# Animation renders without modifiers applied - still image (F12) renders fine

Tags: rendering, modifiers

I use Blender 2.83. Followed a YouTube tutorial to create an audio visualizer. Everything works great in viewport, and rendered as still image. However, when I render an animation, the main object in my scene is rendered without modifiers applied. This occasionally also happens when rendering with F12, but rarely.

There are no error messages in the system console. Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug?

Images attached:

- Viewport
- F12 Still
- Animation

Any help welcome! Thanks!

[image: Screenshot from viewport]

[image: F12 Still Render]

[image: Animation render]